# angular ComponentFactoryResolver inherit parent css

Tags: angular

This article explains how to use `pseudo-class` to inherit parent css.

https://alligator.io/angular/styles-between-components-angular/

This method can be used in child component or dynamic child component.

but, When I using dynamic component, and there is a need for more css to define, I need to do a lot of pseudo-class, like this:

```
:host ::ng-deep .content{
  background: #999;
}
:host ::ng-deep .text{
  border: solid;
}
:host ::ng-deep .head{
  color: #9999;
}
:host  ::ng-deep .root{
  flex: 1 1 1;
}
.
.
.
```

I need to define a lot of `:host` `::ng-deep`. Is there any other better way?
I need to apply all the child dynamic component.

Comment: In my opinion the bast way to get a good clear styling is to disable the `ViewEncapsulation` to `None` and then give your components a good old `id` and `class` structure. That makes it better readable, debuggable and cleaner with in a good structured scss file/folder structure. The only important thing is to think of a good hirarchical class structure. nothing more, nothing less, but thats my opinion.

Comment: Thank you, but I hope the file is clearly differentiated. I am worried that more problems will be derived, when I set `ViewEncapsulation` to `None`.

Comment: @Finn Did you find a way to apply inherit parent CSS when using factoryResolver to inject dynamic childrens?